# how to fix when i switch tab value delta time is change

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

when switch tab 5-10 sec and switch back value is changed because fps drop to 8fps and back to normal how to fix.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior.  From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame):

> `requestAnimationFrame()` calls are paused in most browsers when running
> in background tabs or hidden `<iframe>`s in order to improve performance
> and battery life.